# HOw to rebuild Django tables?

Tags: django

I was having problems with my dB, so I dropped the tables for one of my Django apps. I then ran makemigrations for the app and tried to migrate. It said everything was up to date. It didn't re-create the dropped tables.

How can I get Django to re-build the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only drop your app tables and need to recreate the tables again. You also need to remove all the migrations entry from you app in the `django_migrations` table.

After you have done that you can run `migrate` again. Or if you want to reset your migrations files, remove all migrations from that app and run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete all the files in `app/migrations`, except `__init__.py`

```
project
    app1
        migrations
            __init__.py # do not delete
            000_initial.py # delete

        urls.py
        models.py
        ...
    app2
        migrations
            __init__.py # do not delete
            000_initial.py # delete

        urls.py
        models.py
        ...
   ...
```

Then you can run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I already tried this. On migrate, it simply says No migrations to apply and the file 0001_initial.py is created. But not the tables in the dB.

Comment: You have to remove migrations for each app in your project